# how to create a folder in network drive

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io

To create a dynamic folder in local drive it was generating, if suppose we need to create a folder in network path  means error say that cannot access to the path is denied, how to resolve this issue , i m working on vb.net

Comment: any code? What have you tried so far? If you're doing VB.NET why did you tag it C# ?

Answer (score 0):

Same as creating a directory on a local drive, via [Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) - Of course, the share needs to be set up to allow directory creations, and the user that your application (and specifically the thread) needs to have sufficient permissions as well.